# Assign value of a select in php variable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, cakephp-2.0

How do I get the selected value from a select and already print it? I have a simple form, when the user select the value I want to assign to a php variable, because I will show the selected amount and selected amount x the value of the selected ticket.
All on the same page without input

```html
<div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="form-group">
    <select id="cb_catinsumo" class="form-control   select_ticket" name="teste">
      <option value="0">0</option>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
      <option value="6">6</option>
      <option value="7">7</option>
      <option value="8">8</option>
      <option value="9">9</option>
      <option value="10">10</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try following code :

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    // your php code...
    $x = $_POST['teste'];
}
```

your html code...

Comment: This way solves if I'm to give a right submit? The problem that the buy button will be the last step, I need it at the moment that it select the quantity in the select I capture this value in some way and assign it to a variable because I am going to add that quantity to a variable that is storing the price

Answer (score 1):

```html
<div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="form-group">
    <select id="cb_catinsumo" class="form-control   select_ticket" name="teste">
      <option value="0">0</option>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
      <option value="6">6</option>
      <option value="7">7</option>
      <option value="8">8</option>
      <option value="9">9</option>
      <option value="10">10</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="selectedValue"></div>


<script language="text/javascript">

    jQuery('select#cb_catinsumo').on("change",function(){
        var selectedValue = $(this).val();
        console.log(selectedValue);
        jQuery("div#selectedValue").html(selectedValue);
    });
</script>
```